# Text overflow issue

Tags: php, html

I'm a bit perplexed by this, I'm sure it isn't a problem with css as inputting a string into the same container doesn't create an overflow. E.g:

```
echo '<p class="text"> '. $comment .' This is just random text</p>';
```

The `$comment` will display the data from the database in one line which completely overflows my paragraph tag (Which is position relative just for reference) but the 'This is just random text' breaks as soon as the paragraph width ends. The data type for the `$comment` is just text inside phpmyadmin.

**css:**

```
.text {
position: relative;
left: 10%;
width: 80%;
line-height: 1;
color: #b1bbc3;
font-size: 0.90em;
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
font-weight: 400;
}
```

This is just inside a list tag.

Anyone have a solution for this? After checking further, when I checked the page source, I noticed whenever I get output from the database using `$comments`, even with an echo (not wrapped in html tags), I can see wrapped in double quotes which are not displayed on the page nor in the database. Since I'm selecting all comments, I'm not sure where the double quotes are coming from or whether they're causing this problem/my query is.

My query is as simple as

```
$sql = "SELECT comments FROM db WHERE username = '$username'";
```

Comment: Could you show a picture of how it looks, show an example of the $comments-content, and the surrounding HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes when the text is not wrapping it's caused by unexpected characters in place of where the spaces or word breaks should be. To test what characters are being output, use the following code and verify that the content is as expected.

```
<pre>
<?php
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($comment); $i++) {
    echo $i . " " . bin2hex($comment[$i]) . " " . $comment[$i] . "\n";
}
?>
</pre>
```

This will print out each character in the string vertically:

```
0 6f o
1 6e n
2 65 e
3 20  
4 74 t
5 77 w
6 6f o
```

Space will appear as 20, new lines as 0d followed by 0a, or just 0a.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, the problem stopped persisting for some unknown reason after I took a break which makes me paranoid, while the quotes still persist. I tested this aswell and returned similar results however didn't show any new lines. I was hoping it would come up with the double quotes, I don't understand where they're coming from.